# Open Database from Assets...always FileNotFoundException

Tags: java, android, sqlite, fragment, sqliteopenhelper

I have already created an SQLite database. It's up and running...
Now, I want to make a backup copy(if possible in the same folder) but after 4 hours I can't.
I read a lot of posts regarding this issue...this is my code in DBHelper:

```
public void copyDataBase(String itinerario, Context c) throws IOException {

        InputStream mInputStream = c.getAssets().open(Constants.DB_NAME);
        String outFileName = DB_PATH+Constants.DB_NAME+itinerario;
        OutputStream mOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int length;
        while ((length = mInputStream.read(buffer)) > 0) {
            mOutputStream.write(buffer, 0, length);
        }
        mOutputStream.flush();
        mOutputStream.close();
        mInputStream.close();


}
```

- Constants.Name is right (MYDB)
- If I browse /data/data//databases/ I can find the DB
  -I tried with explicit path and other solution founded in Internet but without luck!

It always return a FileNotFoundException.

I'm using fragments so I pass Context from Fragment to this method

May be that I make a lame mistake but after 4 hours I don't find errors...the code is quite clear

Can someone help me ?
Thanks in advance
Alex

Comment: All what you write makes no sense. There is no consistency in what you tell. Starting with "already created an SQLite database. It's up and running...`. If your code works and the database is in use then what does it have to do with assets?

Comment: You are in right. Briefly I thought that when a DB was created in /data/data/<package>/databases was possible to make a copy for backup purpose with other name in the same subfolder and have two databases . So after I have understood the problem (reading assets doc) I modified the code to make a backup of all tables in the same DB.

Comment: `Briefly I thought that when a DB was created in /data/data/<package>/databases was possible to make a copy for backup purpose with other name in the same subfolder`. Well that is ok. That is perfectly possible as it is just a file in internal memory. So you could indeed do that: make a copy of that file. Which has nothing to do with assets. I still wonder why you again mentioned assets.

Comment: So the original file would be `/data/user/0/com.example.alex.navdemo/databases/expenses_traker.db` and the copy `/data/user/0/com.example.alex.navdemo/databases/expenses_traker.db.copy`.

Comment: exactly, that was what I wanted but without success, so I used a workaround and I made a backup of tables inside the first database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `Context#getDatabasePath(String)`. https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getDatabasePath(java.lang.String)